# What is the R equivalent to Excel's =2*NORMSDIST(2)

Tags: r, excel

In Excel `=2*NORMSDIST(2)` puts out ~1.96. How do I get that same value in R?

Comment: You are looking for `qnorm`

Comment: `qnorm` is the quantile function and thus is undefined outside `[0,1]`

Comment: I am thinking that you actually do want `pval <- 0.05; qnorm(1 - pval/2)` - inspect the code of `confint.default` and ask yourself why the smart people that wrote R chose to go down that path.

Comment: You're almost certainly Doing It Wrong. You want `=normsinv(0.975)` to get the 95% confidence limit for a z-score. The fact that your formula gives approximately the right number is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to get the two-sided 95% confidence limit for a z-score, you would use `=NORMSINV(0.975)` (which is `=NORMSINV(1 - (1-0.95)/2)`). The fact that your formula gives approximately the same number is nothing more than a coincidence.

The equivalent in R would be `qnorm(0.975)` or `qnorm(1 - (1-0.95)/2)`.

Answer (score 9):

You can get that value in R with

```
2*pnorm(2)
```

The `pnorm()` function is the cumulative density function for a normal random variable

[image]

Which is consistent with the description of the Excel `NORMDIST` function

> NORMSDIST(z) returns the probability that the observed value of a standard normal random variable will be less than or equal to z. A standard normal random variable has mean 0 and standard deviation 1 (and also variance 1 because variance = standard deviation squared).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why one would choose to use `pnorm` if their goal is to make a confidence interval.  It seems they really should be looking for `qnorm`

Comment: Well I certainly don't associate Excel with statistical rigor I rarely think that users ever are knowingly doing the wrong thing - they might just be blissfully ignorant.

Comment: @MrFlick There's a difference between lack of statistical rigor, and just plain getting it wrong.

Comment: 2 * pnorm(2) puts out ~1.96 and also obtains the answer in the OP. It is the equivalent of 2*NORMSDIST(2) in Excel. If one were to obtain a 95% CI, they could use this approach in R. qnorm(1 - .05/2) is a different method. However, qnorm is more specific for generating 95% CIs and, though not the same, is generally used instead for 95% CIs.

Answer (score 3):

R Equivalent for `=NORMSDIST(2)` is `pnorm(2)`

R Equivalent for `=NORMSINV(0.95)` is `qnorm(0.95)`